# How to combine unlike streams in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Set<DateCount>` which I create using the following code.  This creates a set of 7 `DateCount` objects with an initial count of 0, one for each day of the current week starting from the current day.

```
// Create an initial Set of DateCount objects for the current week with counts of 0
Set<DateCount> dateCounts = IntStream.range(0, DAYS_IN_WEEK)
        .mapToObj(idx -> new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay().plusDays(idx))
        .map(dt -> new DateCount(dt.toDate(), 0L))
        .collect(toSet());
```

I have a `List<Object[]>` which is returned from a database repository.  Each `Object[]` in the list has a `BigDecimal` at index 0 and a `Long` at index 1.  The `BigDecimal` is actually a date, something like `20141001`.  What I'm wondering is if there is a way I can update the `dateCounts` set using this data in a Stream fashion.  Right now, I'm doing the following which just iterates over the list of object arrays and creates new `DateCount` objects that are then added to the `dateCounts` set.  The `DateCount` class has a custom `equals()` and `hashCode()` method to ensure the `dateCounts` set contains only a single `DateCount` instance for any given date.

```
data.stream()
        .forEach(obj -> {
            DateTime date = null;
            try {
                date = (sdf == null) ? new DateTime(obj[0]) : new DateTime(sdf.parse(obj[0].toString()));
                dateCounts.add(new DateCount(date.toDate(), (Long) obj[1]));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

On a side note, I'm wondering if there's also a way to avoid doing a try/catch in my lambda expression just for parsing a `String` to a `Date`.

**Update** -- This is what I've come up with so far.  It doesn't seem natural though to stream over the `List<Object[]>` within the .map call, not sure if there's a better way.  I introduced my own `Tuple<X, Y>` class because working with an `Object[]` in streams doesn't work very well given there's no accessor methods.  Also in the last 2 lines, I'm creating a `TreeSet` with a `Comparator` so that I can sort the data by date.  I don't feel that's the best approach, but I tried calling `sorted()` and making `DateCount` implement `Comparable` which seems to work fine, but as soon as the `collect(toSet())` method is called, the sorting goes out the window.  I assume that's the nature of it being a streamed call.  I'm curious if there's a way to sort it though before the collect method call and retain the sort after calling collect.

```
Set<DateCount> dateCounts = IntStream.range(0, DAYS_IN_WEEK)
        .mapToObj(idx -> new Tuple<>(new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay().plusDays(idx).toDate(), 0L))
        .map(t -> {
            Tuple<String, Long> d = data.stream()
                    .map(arr -> new Tuple<>(arr[0].toString(), (Long) arr[1]))
                    .filter(tuple -> sdf.format(t.getX()).equals(tuple.getX()))
                    .findFirst().orElse(new Tuple<>(sdf.format(t.getX()), 0L));

            return new DateCount(DateTime.parse(d.getX(), DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd")).toDate(), d.getY());
        })
        .collect(toSet());

TreeSet<DateCount> set = new TreeSet<>((a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));
set.addAll(dateCounts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a `Supplier` for the collection. Just replace

```
.collect(toSet());
```

with

```
.collect(toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>((a, b) -> a.compareTo(b))));
```

But note, that specifying `(a, b) -> a.compareTo(b)` for the `Comparator` implies *natural ordering*. If your elements implement `Comparable`, it is unnecessary to provide such a comparator. You can simply use

```
.collect(toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

If `DateCount` has a `compareTo` method but does not implement `Comparator` you could also specify `DateCount::compareTo` rather than `(a, b) -> a.compareTo(b)`.

---

Note that in your first `mapToObj` operation it is unnecessary to wrap the `DateTime` in a `Tuple`. You can simply map to `DateTime` and use that value in the next `map` operation (as I see only `t.getX()` there, the second value which is `0L` is not used at all).

---

After all, I’m not sure what you are trying to achieve but I have the strong feeling, that you might have a look at [`Collectors.groupingBy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-)…

Comment: Thanks, the Supplier approach looks good.  My main discomfort was the nested streaming of data `data.stream()`.  And it looks like you're right about not needing to map to a `Tuple` in my initial `mapToObj`.  I'll look into the groupingBy method.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can map your database data to a `Map<DateTime,Long>` for quick look-ups so you only have to process it once. Then as you stream through your `Set<DateCount>` you can pull in updated values using `peek()`. Here's an example. I used `Date` in place of `DateTime` just to make it easier to code the example.

```
Instant baseDate = Instant.now();
Date date1 = new Date(baseDate.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toEpochMilli());
Date date2 = new Date(baseDate.plus(2, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toEpochMilli());
Date date3 = new Date(baseDate.plus(3, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toEpochMilli());

Set<DateCount> dateCounts = new TreeSet<DateCount>(); // Our mock Set
dateCounts.add(new DateCount(date1, 0L));
dateCounts.add(new DateCount(date2, 0L));
dateCounts.add(new DateCount(date3, 0L));

List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>(); // Our mock database Data      
data.add(new Object[]{date1.toInstant().toEpochMilli(), 5L});
data.add(new Object[]{date2.toInstant().toEpochMilli(), 3L});
data.add(new Object[]{date3.toInstant().toEpochMilli(), 2L});

//Map our data so we only have to process it once, and then we can look it up
Map<Date,Long> mappedData = data.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(k->new Date((long) k[0]), v->(Long)v[1]));

//Update the data using peek as we stream through it
dateCounts.stream()
    .peek(dc->dc.setCount(mappedData.get(dc.getDate())))
    .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

When run, here's the output, so that you can see the dateCounts are updated:

```
DateCount: Thu Dec 25 11:25:56 EST 2014 - 5
DateCount: Fri Dec 26 11:25:56 EST 2014 - 3
DateCount: Sat Dec 27 11:25:56 EST 2014 - 2
```

And here's the implementation of DateCount I used to make the above code work... I imagine it's not too dissimilar to yours:

```
public class DateCount implements Comparable<DateCount>{
    private Date date = null;
    private Long count = 0L;

    public DateCount(Date datetime, Long count){
        this.date = datetime;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void setDateTime(Date date){
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date getDate(){
        return date;
    }

    public void setCount(long count){
        this.count = count;
    }

    public long getCount(){
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return date.hashCode() + 459;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        boolean result = false;
        if (o instanceof DateCount){
            DateCount other = (DateCount) o;
            result = this.compareTo(other) == 0;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DateCount other) {
        if (this.date == null){
            return other.getDate() == null ? 0 : -1;
        } else {
            return date.compareTo(other.getDate());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "DateCount: " + date.toString() + " - " + count;
    }
}
```