# Collecting elements of a stream in Java 8 and reducing some of those elements into a single element in the resulting collection

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

The following stream operation results in a `Stream<DateCount>` where each element represents a sequence of dates with associated counts.  If I have elements from Monday to Sunday and I want to summarize Friday, Saturday or Sunday into a single new `DateCount` element, how would I achieve that?  Ultimately, my resulting stream should only contain elements for Monday to Friday, but the count for Friday should be a sum of the counts from Friday, Saturday and Sunday.  I think I need to create a `Collector` for this, but I'm not sure how to make the collector return what I'm looking for.

```
IntStream.range(0, days)
        .mapToObj(idx -> new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay().minusDays(idx).toDate())
        .map(date -> {
            Tuple<Date, Long> dateLongTuple = data.stream()
                    .map(arr -> new Tuple<>(DateTime.parse(arr[0].toString(), DATE_FORMATTER).toDate(), (Long) arr[1]))
                    .filter(tuple -> date.equals(tuple.getX()))
                    .findFirst().orElse(new Tuple<>(date, 0L));

            return new DateCount(dateLongTuple.getX(), dateLongTuple.getY());
        })
```

Comment: Readers may interested in the clear simple examples of Streams usage (including iteration through collections to filter out members) in the article, [Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams, Part 1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html), published in Oracle’s [Java Magazine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamagazine/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
List<IntPair<DayOfWeek>> result = Arrays.stream(DayOfWeek.values())
        .map(day -> new IntPair<>(day, 1))
        .collect(ArrayList::new,
                (list, pair) -> {
                    switch (pair.x) {
                        case SATURDAY:
                        case SUNDAY:
                            list.get(list.size() - 1).add(pair.y);
                            break;
                        default:
                            list.add(pair);
                    }
                },
                ArrayList::addAll);
System.out.println(result);
```

My tuple implementation:

```
class IntPair<T> {
    T x;
    int y;

    IntPair(T x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    void add(int i) {
        y += i;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is completely correct because it uses a DayOfWeek as the IntPair type.  In my app, the data returned from the database contains an actual Date, it is not just day of week specific.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit underspecified:

- Are the days unique within the stream?
- Does the stream only cover one week or, if not, shall the days be aggregated per day-of-week or still be distinct days of the calendar but just the three adjacent days be aggregated?
- *How* should they be aggregated? You are referring to a class `DateCount`, we don’t know, but using a `Tuple<Date, Long>` in your code example.
- You don’t seem to use the Java 8 date/time API. Which API are you using and why don’t you use the Java 8 API?

Maybe you have an [“XY Problem”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/242352).

I’ll give you an example using the Java 8 API which might be closer to your actual task (by utilizing the information of [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26152692/2711488)):

- Creating a stream out of a two dimensional array of `BigInteger` and `Long` objects which I assume to represent calendar days and a count
- filter them to contain the days of a specific range, i.e. one week starting at today
- group them by their day-of-week, which is now unique due to the limited range, summing up the `long` values
- Other than your previous question, we will treat `SATURDAY` and `SUNDAY` like `FRIDAY`, forming a single group

…

```
long min = LocalDate.now().getLong(ChronoField.EPOCH_DAY),
     max=min+DayOfWeek.values().length;

Map<DayOfWeek, Long> map = data.stream()
  .map(arr -> new Tuple<TemporalAccessor,Long>(
       DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE.parse(arr[0].toString()), (Long)arr[1]))
  .filter(t->{ long d=t.getX().getLong(ChronoField.EPOCH_DAY); return d>=min&&d<max;})
  .collect(groupingBy(t -> weekdayOrFriday(t.getX()), summingLong(t -> t.getY())));
System.out.println(map);

static DayOfWeek weekdayOrFriday(TemporalAccessor d) {
    final DayOfWeek day = DayOfWeek.from(d);
    switch(day) {
        default: return day;
        case SATURDAY: case SUNDAY: return DayOfWeek.FRIDAY;
    }
}
```

Here is an alternative solution which will group to calendar days (after collapsing weekend days to their preceding Friday) which will be the right solution if the range might be larger than one week and you don’t actually want to aggregate same weekdays.

```
LocalDate min=LocalDate.now(), max=min.plusDays(DayOfWeek.values().length);
data.stream()
    .map(arr -> new Tuple<TemporalAccessor,Long>(
            DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE.parse(arr[0].toString()), (Long)arr[1]))
    .map(t->new Tuple<LocalDate,Long>(fridayarize(t.getX()), t.getY()))
    .filter(t -> !t.getX().isBefore(min) && t.getX().isBefore(max) )
    .collect(groupingBy(Tuple::getX, TreeMap::new, summingLong(Tuple::getY)))
    .forEach((date,count)->System.out.println(date+"\t: "+count));

static LocalDate fridayarize(TemporalAccessor d) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.from(d);
    switch(DayOfWeek.from(d)) {
        default: return date;
        case SATURDAY: return date.minusDays(1);
        case SUNDAY: return date.minusDays(2);
    }
}
```

But I will refrain from posting more solutions until you made a more precise description of you actual problem…